# How to remove deleted resource from cloudformation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I deployed a stack to AWS but manually deleted some resources which causing the stack out of sync. I am able to use `drift detection` to detect the deleted resources. But how can I force the stack template to remove these resources?

I know I can import some resources to an existing stack manually via AWS console but how can I remove some from the stack?

Comment: Did you try simply deleting the resources from the source CloudFormation template and then updating the stack with that modified template?

Comment: CF will try to delete them so it fails and complaining such resources don't exist.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to validate this. You're able to manually delete a resource that was provisioned through CF (which arguably you should not be allowed to do) so it's odd that you don't have a way to then fix the stack.

Comment: For a pretty basic CloudFormation stack comprising an IAM policy, DynamoDB table, and S3 bucket, I was able to manually delete the table and bucket, then remove the corresponding resources from my template, and then run a stack update and it all went smoothly.

Comment: Maybe It is related to resources dependency, can you check that?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me just now was to set the "Preserve successfully provisioned resources" option.  This still complained about being unable to delete resources that were already deleted, but clicking the "Update" button after that allowd it all to go through happliy

[image]